# Backlight not working on toshiba sattelite C660

Tags: kernel, backlight

I am trying to get backlight working on my laptop. It worked on ubuntu before so I don't really understand why it is not working atm. I also tried the vendor flags in grub already.

here some extra information: http://hastebin.com/kogazivida.avrasm

Answer (score 2):

I just figured it out... .

1. `sudo nvidia-xconfig`
2. `sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf`
3. Add `Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"` to the device section.
4. `sudo reboot`